# Validar password html y evitar redireccionamiento

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tratando de validar que dos contraseñas sean iguales mediante JS. `pass_validar.js:`

```
function validarPasswords(){
  var pass = document.getElementsById("contrasena").value;
  var repass = document.getElementsById("recontrasena").value;

  if(!pass.equals(repass)){
    pass.focus();
    alert('Las contraseñas no son iguales.');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Luego, en mi `index.html` llamo a mi archivo `js`:

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pass_validar.js"></script>
</head>
```

Y en mi formulario hago lo siguiente:

```
  <form method="post" action="gustos.html">

      <label for="contrasena"><b>Contraseña: </b></label>
      <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña..." required>

      <label for="recontrasena"><b>Repetir Contraseña: </b></label>
      <input type="password" name="recontrasena" id="contrasena" placeholder="Confirme su contraseña..." required>

     
      <button type="submit" onsubmit="validarPasswords();" class="registerbtn">Registrar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Pero, al poner dos contraseñas distintas, me sigue mandando a la otra pantalla, ¿QUé estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo un Ejemplo Funcional:

```html
<html>
<form method="post" action="gustos.html" id="frm">

<label for="contrasena"><b>Contraseña: </b></label>
<input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" value="" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña..." required>
<label for="recontrasena"><b>Repetir Contraseña: </b></label>
<input type="password" name="recontrasena" id="recontrasena" value="" placeholder="Confirme su contraseña..." required>
<input type="button" value="Registrar" onclick="validarPasswords()">
</form>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validarPasswords(){
  var pass = document.getElementById("contrasena").value;
  var repass = document.getElementById("recontrasena").value;

    if (pass!=repass) 
    {
        alert("Las Contraseñas no Coinsiden");
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("frm").submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

Cosas que mejore:

-El submit lo hago con JS

-El id de Contrasena estaba dupplicado

-Solo valide con != (Diferente de)

-Agregue ID a tu formulario para manejarlo mejor

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que tu id de la contraseña repetida es exactamente el mismo que el de la primera contraseña

cámbialo así:

```
  <form method="post" action="gustos.html">

  <label for="contrasena"><b>Contraseña: </b></label>
  <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña..." required>

  <label for="recontrasena"><b>Repetir Contraseña: </b></label>
  <input type="password" name="recontrasena" id="recontrasena" placeholder="Confirme su contraseña..." required>

 
  <button type="submit" onsubmit="validarPasswords();" class="registerbtn">Registrar</button>
</div>
```

y con eso debería funcionarte. Espero que te ayude!

**EDIT**

ok, creo que ya conseguí arreglarlo:

```
<form method="post" action="gustos.html">

  <label for="contrasena"><b>Contraseña: </b></label>
  <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña..." required>

  <label for="recontrasena"><b>Repetir Contraseña: </b></label>
  <input type="password" name="recontrasena" id="recontrasena" placeholder="Confirme su contraseña..." required>

 
  <button type="submit" onclick="JavaScript:return validarPasswords();" class="registerbtn">Registrar</button>
```

si te fijas agregue el "JavaScript:return" en el boton, para que esperara la respuesta de la función, y modifiqué el script así:

```
        var pass = document.getElementById("contrasena");
        var repass = document.getElementById("recontrasena");


  if(pass != repass){
    pass.focus();
    alert('Las contraseñas no son iguales.');
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, no me ha funcionado

Comment: Ya edité, a ver si con eso funciona

Comment: ah, no había visto que ya habían añadido otra respuesta.